# highcharts reversed x-axis label stepping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have several highcharts graphs that display data over a date-range that can be customized by the user. In cases where the range specified is very long and granular, I tell highcharts to skip x-axis labels by setting xAxis.options.labels.step to some value n.

My problem is that this usually results in the last date on the x-axis not being displayed. Highcharts will by default always show the first (left-most) date, then show every nth label up to the edge of the graph, but this won't always include the final label.

For my use case, I would prefer the opposite: I want the final date to always be displayed and then show every nth date moving to the left, not necessarily including the first date. Is there a knob I'm missing that would allow me to tweak highcharts to obtain this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to set showLastLabel ?http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.showLastLabel or use tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner to define function which set ticks "dynamically"

Comment: I did try showLastLabel but it didn't do anything by itself. I tried combining it with endOnTick but that created an extra tick with no data point. I didn't see the tickPositioner...I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: Alright I managed to set up tickPositioner such that the labels show up but they're formatted wrong. The x-axis values are specified in ms-since-epoch and we have the axis set up with dateTimeLabelFormats to show the date correctly. However, when I use the tickPositioner, this formatting is not applied. If i apply it manually in the tickPositioner function, the x-axis labels fail to show up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use tickPositioner and just apply the date formatting manually. I managed to find a way to do this such that the x-axis labels show up appropriately.